# Declaring an anonymous function outside main() at package level in go lang gives error

Tags: function, go, anonymous

I am getting compilation error while declaring anonymous function outside main() block. I am curious about the scope of anonymous function in go. Assigning to a variable works but without assignment it does not work. What is the difference between both the piece of codes ???

This code does **not** work !!
`

```
package main
import "fmt"

func(){
      fmt.Println("Welcome! from Anonymous function")
}

func main() {
        printme := ()
}
```

`
This piece of code works !!

`

```
package main
import "fmt"

var pri = func(){
      fmt.Println("Welcome! from Anonymous function")
}

func main() {

        pri()
}
```

`
Error it gives for the not working portion is:

## command-line-arguments

./anony-func-2.go:8:7: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting name or (
./anony-func-2.go:8:8: method has no receiver
./anony-func-2.go:14:14: syntax error: unexpected ), expecting expression

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from this [blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/main-and-init-function-in-golang/):

> The `main()` function is a special type of function and it is the
> entry point of the executable programs. It does not take any argument
> nor return anything. Go automatically call main() function, so there
> is no need to call main() function explicitly and every executable
> program must contain single main package and main() function.

Which means that no other function except the `main()` function will be invoked, so it makes no sense to have an anonymous function outside `main()` since it will not be called anyways.